# When make "Size" class to json, It is something weird in .net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, jsonserializer

I had used `Size` class to store width/height of something. But `Size` class can store only `integer` value. So I created `MySize` class made up of `double`s and used it.

And weird thing was occurred. Serializing class `Size` and class `MySize` to json gives different results.

##### Sources

```
 public class MySize
 {
     [JsonConstructor]
     public MySize() { }
     public MySize(double _Width, double _Height)
     {
         Width = _Width;
         Height = _Height;
     }
     public double Width { get; set; }
     public double Height { get; set; }
 }

public async Task<IActionResult> test()
{
    Size test = new Size(0, 0);
    MySize test2 = new MySize(1, 1);
    var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
    var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test2);
    Console.WriteLine(json1);
    Console.WriteLine(json2);
}
```

##### Result of "Size" Class to json

```
"valiable" : "0, 0"
```

##### Result of "MySize" Class to json

```
"valiable" : {
    "Width" : 0,
    "Height" : 0,
}
```

What is the different in both?

Comment: A side note: `Size` is not a class but a struct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.size?view=net-7.0.

Comment: Not really weird when you consider that _System.Drawing.Size_ is annotated with a `[TypeConverter]` attribute that is specifying [_System.Drawing.SizeConverter_](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/System/Drawing/SizeConverter.cs,65) as the type converter for the _Size_ data type. And Newtonsoft.Json adheres to such type converter annoations and uses it to convert _Size_ instances from/to a string during de/serialization.